# Please explain the logic behind Kernighan's bit counting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit

This question directly follows after reading through  [Bits counting algorithm (Brian Kernighan) in an integer time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380478/bits-counting-algorithm-brian-kernighan-in-an-integer-time-complexity) . The Java code in question is

```
int count_set_bits(int n) {
  int count = 0;
    while(n != 0) {
      n &= (n-1);
      count++;
    }
 }
```

I want to understand what `n &= (n-1)` is achieving here ? I have seen a similar kind of construct in another nifty algorithm for detecting whether a number is a power of 2 like:

```
if(n & (n-1) == 0) {
    System.out.println("The number is a power of 2");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bits counting algorithm (Brian Kernighan) in an integer time complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380478/bits-counting-algorithm-brian-kernighan-in-an-integer-time-complexity)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Stepping through the code in a debugger helped me.

If you start with

```
n = 1010101 & n-1=1010100 => 1010100
n = 1010100 & n-1=1010011 => 1010000
n = 1010000 & n-1=1001111 => 1000000
n = 1000000 & n-1=0111111 => 0000000
```

So this iterates 4 times.  Each iteration decrements the value in such a way that the least significant bit that is set to 1 disappears.

Decrementing by one flips the lowest bit and every bit up to the first one. e.g. if you have 1000....0000 -1 = 0111....1111 not matter how many bits it has to flip and it stops there leaving any other bits set untouched. When you and this with `n` the lowest bit set and only the lowest bit becomes `0`

Comment: You're fast, was only half-way through pretty much the same description :)

Comment: @pap I jump onto questions rather quick, should stop that. ;)

Comment: The reason being `1000... - 1 = 0111...` so bitwise and gives you `0000...`

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction of 1 from a number toggles all the bits (from right to left) till the rightmost set bit(including the righmost set bit). 
So if we subtract a number by 1 and do bitwise & with itself `(n & (n-1))`, we unset the righmost set bit. In this way we can unset 1s one by one from right to left in  loop.

> The number of times the loop iterates is equal to the number of set
>   bits.

Source : [Brian Kernighan's Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/)