# How to check the number of set bits in an 8-bit unsigned char?

Tags: c, embedded, bit

So I have to find the set bits (on 1) of an unsigned char variable in C?

A similar question is [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023) But it uses an algorithm that's not easily adaptable to 8-bit unsigned chars (or its not apparent).

Comment: The cited duplicate and Community Wiki answer uses an `int` or 32-bit wide variable. The use of a signed int in the cited dup produces undefined results in C/C++ due to use of `operator >>`. Here is one of the comments on that code: *".... you are not meant to understand or maintain this code, just worship the gods that revealed it to mankind."* Its not clear to me how Flav is supposed to use the answer in the cited dup to answer ***his*** question, given its not readily understandable or maintainable.

Comment: I reopened this question because the approach that can be taken with 8-bit variables is not possible to use for 32-bit variables discussed in the duplicate.

Comment: @jww seems to me that that answer should be edited to use `uint32_t` .. looks like nobody has been brave enough to do so!  Or at least, clarify the preceding sentence .

Comment: @Matt - check out the edit history. I think it went from `signed int` to `uint32_t` to `int`. I avoided the edit precisely because of the edit history. (I'm abrasive at times, but its not my intent to start a battle on this one).

Comment: @Flav - you have the embedded tag. What is the processor? Some processors have an ASM instruction to do it. i386 and x84_64 lack it (IIRC), but ARM has it with `VCNT`.

Comment: @jww: VCNT is an ARM-NEON instruction. Wish the Cortex-M would have it, but it actually does _not_. As much as ARM7 for instance.

Comment: @jww: Could you please point me where I actually _do_ state that? All I say is that not all ARM CPUs do have VCNT. From your comment one has to get the impression that VCNT is actually provided by all ARM CPUs, which is simply not true. Get the logic right: ARM-NEON is a subset of ARM, but **not** ARM as a whole. And: yes. **Most** ARM CPUs in the world do not have NEON. Have a look at the market shares for Cortex-M0(+)/3/4 and ARM7/ARM9.

Comment: @Olaf - I think you are detracting from the question and the potential answers. At minimum, you are polluting comments. Let the fellow answer the question on what processor he has. Stop with the vanity comments, about how you think the world should work or what the implementation should favor (memory versus time trade-offs). You did it here, and you did it on at least two answers below. They call it [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/). Just because you have an opinion does not mean you should share it with us. After 2 or 3 of the badgerings, folks like me lose patience with folks like you.

Comment: @jww: Yeah, I prefer logical conclusions; no assumptions. One should not confuse Rep here with rep in real live. Argumentum ad verecundiam? How poor!

Comment: *"One should not confuse Rep here with rep in real live..."* - absolutely. No arguments from me. *"I prefer logical conclusions; not assumptions"* - like your assumption about processors; or your assumption about goals, like memory versus time trade-offs. Or your comments on what would constitute the best inline assembly code. One of you best in this question is I was uninformed because I provided alternatives. I chose not to add a ["mee too"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) answer, and simply offered some alternatives without repeating answers.

Comment: @jww: Ok, I'll try to setle this and hope you will also: You actually stated here and in your answer that "ARM has a VCNT" instruction. All I did now, was to make clear that **not** all ARM CPUs actually do. Among those are the mostly used embedded ARM Cortex-M as much as the older ARM7 CPUs. So, one **cannot assume** `ARM == VCNT avaliable` as _your_ statement implies. That was all! For code generation: See my statement about reps IRL.

Comment: @jww: You are very welcome just to ignore my posts. Me for myself have no need for such verbicide.

Comment: @Olaf - *"You are very welcome just to ignore my posts."* - actually, we don't have a way to add folks like you to a killfile until your behavior improves. See, for example, [Does Stack Overflow or Meta have a Killfile equivalent?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290851).

Answer (score 8):

The algorithm suggested in the question [*How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023) is trivially adapted to 8 bit:

```
int NumberOfSetBits( uint8_t b )
{
     b = b - ((b >> 1) & 0x55);
     b = (b & 0x33) + ((b >> 2) & 0x33);
     return (((b + (b >> 4)) & 0x0F) * 0x01);
}
```

It is simply a case of shortening the constants the the least significant eight bits, and removing the final 24 bit right-shift.  Equally it could be adapted for 16bit using an 8 bit shift.  Note that in the case for 8 bit, the mechanical adaptation of the 32 bit algorithm results in a redundant `* 0x01` which could be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest approach for an 8-bit variable is using a lookup table.

Build an array of 256 values, one per 8-bit combination. Each value should contain the count of bits in its corresponding index:

```
int bit_count[] = {
// 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a, ... FE FF
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, ..., 7, 8
};
```

Getting a count of a combination is the same as looking up a value from the `bit_count` array. The advantage of this approach is that it is very fast.

You can generate the array using a simple program that counts bits one by one in a slow way:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int p = 0 ; p != 8 ; p++) {
        if (i & (1 << p)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d, ", count);
}
```

([demo that generates the table](http://ideone.com/Zip9kR)).

If you would like to trade some CPU cycles for memory, you can use a 16-byte lookup table for two 4-bit lookups:

```
static const char split_lookup[] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4
};

int bit_count(unsigned char n) {
    return split_lookup[n&0xF] + split_lookup[n>>4];
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/xjS9Bz).

Comment: That is fast, but apparently very memory-consuming. Not the best idea for an (potential) 8 bit MCU. For a harvard-MCU, this can easily be even slower.

Comment: @Olaf 256 bytes (which can be easily shrunk to 128 bytes by packing counts into 4-bit nibbles) could hardly be classified as "memory consuming" except in the tiniest of the embedded systems (PICs come to mind). Even on 8-bit systems from long time back (68HC11 with 16..32K of ROM) 256 bytes was not too much. As far as the speed goes, this would be hard to beat, too: on HC11 this would take two four-cycle instructions (`LDX` and `LDAA` with `X` as an index).

Comment: You might be surprised. MSP430F2012 comes to mind: 16 bit CPU with 2KiB Flash. and still, the problem with Harvard-Flash is valid. Accesses to Flash might be pretty costly. Note also, that for am STM32F4x MCU, Flash adds multiple waitstates and can interrupt instruction prefetch. All issues you should not forget about when recommending your solution as the only right one. On an 8 bit MCU, the additional instrucions also add up (8/16 bit MCUs  often have no barrel shifter).

Comment: @Olaf I don't know, I have been out of embedded development since 1997, so I missed much of what happened in nearly two decades.

Comment: Funny: around that time, I started this as a job (but have done that semi-pro about one decade longer). FYI: as I wrote, there are really still tons of MCUs with few bytes of RAM and litte Flash around. And that is no legacy, gut quite modern devices.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Reading flash in 1997 might be slower than doing this calculation in registers!

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Actually not, as MCUs that time mostly had ROM; Flash just started at that time. Microchip e.g. had no good Flash process until some years later (the PIC16F84 used a very costly implementation). Even with Flash, the Speed of ROM/Flash/whatever was the same as for the MCUs, so no wait states. For modern ARM-Cortex-M this has massively changed. I am sometimes very disappointed how slow these MCUs actually perform running out of Flash - exspecially with data tables in Flash.

Comment: @MattMcNabb In 1997 flash was still a hot new thing, with price tag too high for things that we designed. We used static memory chips with battery backup for persistent data.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Not EPROM? IIRC, OTP (EPROM without glass-window actually) was more or less standard these days.

Comment: @Olaf They put EPROMs in production models, while we always used chips w/glass window for development, testing, and to send out patches to clients (via FedEx :-)

Comment: Good call, dasblinkenlight. I thought table driven, too. the table takes 255 bytes of data. Is there an algorithm like that shown in the question of the previously cited dup? The algorithm would swap memory for time (assuming, say 6 or 8 instructions or 20 to 40 bytes of instruction).

Comment: @jww The inner loop in the code that generates the table or the code in Olaf's answer do counting one bit at a time. Note that you could also pack data into 4-bit nibbles for easy retrieval, or use a split look-up. I'll edit with a split look-up solution and a demo.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Hamming Weight algorithm for 8bits?
If it is true, here is the code:

```
unsigned char in = 22; //This is your input number
unsigned char out = 0;
in = in - ((in>>1) & 0x55);
in = (in & 0x33) + ((in>>2) & 0x33);
out = ((in + (in>>4) & 0x0F) * 0x01) ;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of multiplying by `0x01` in `out = ((in + (in>>4) & 0x0F) * 0x01);`?

Comment: That is the last step of Hamming Weight algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight   . If the input is 16bits, it should be 0x0101

Comment: Multiplication by 1 does not make much sense. For wider input, it does actually.

Answer (score 2):

I made an optimized version. With a 32-bit processor, utilizing multiplication, bit shifting and masking can make smaller code for the same task, especially when the input domain is small (8-bit unsigned integer).

The C23 standard will add a new API called `stdc_count_ones_uc()` (defined in header `<stdbit.h>`). My code is compatible; see the compatibility wrapper in the example code.

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned int bit_count_uint8(uint8_t x)
{
    uint32_t n;
    n = (uint32_t)(x * 0x08040201UL);
    n = (uint32_t)(((n >> 3) & 0x11111111UL) * 0x11111111UL);
    /* The "& 0x0F" will be optimized out but I add it for clarity. */
    return (n >> 28) & 0x0F;
}

/* C23 compatible interface */
#if CHAR_BIT == 8
static inline \
unsigned int stdc_count_ones_uc(unsigned char value)
{
    return bit_count_uint8(value);
}
#endif
```

### Technical notes

- This produces smallest binary code for IA-32, x86-64 and AArch32 (without NEON instruction set) as far as I can find. For ARM NEON please look at [the other answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886191/4606310).
- For x86-64, this doesn't use the fewest number of instructions, but the bit shifts and downcasting avoid the use of 64-bit instructions and therefore save a few bytes in the compiled binary.
- Interestingly, in IA-32 and x86-64, a variant of the above algorithm using a modulo (`(((uint32_t)(x * 0x08040201U) >> 3) & 0x11111111U) % 0x0F`) actually produces larger code, due to a requirement to move the remainder register for return value (`mov eax,edx`) after the `div` instruction. (I tested all of these in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/))

### Explanation

I denote the eight bits of the byte `x`, from MSB to LSB, as *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, *e*, *f*, *g* and *h*.

```
                               abcdefgh
*   00001000 00000100 00000010 00000001 (make 4 copies of x
---------------------------------------  with appropriate
abc defgh0ab cdefgh0a bcdefgh0 abcdefgh  bit spacing)
>> 3                                   
---------------------------------------
    000defgh 0abcdefg h0abcdef gh0abcde
&   00010001 00010001 00010001 00010001
---------------------------------------
    000d000h 000c000g 000b000f 000a000e
*   00010001 00010001 00010001 00010001
---------------------------------------
    000d000h 000c000g 000b000f 000a000e
... 000h000c 000g000b 000f000a 000e
... 000c000g 000b000f 000a000e
... 000g000b 000f000a 000e
... 000b000f 000a000e
... 000f000a 000e
... 000a000e
... 000e
    ^^^^ (Bits 31-28 will contain the sum of the bits
          a, b, c, d, e, f, g and h. Extract these
          bits and we are done.)
```

*(Update 2024-02-29)*

I'll nickname my method in this answer the "multiply-mask-multiply" method, and the modulo variant "multiply-mask-modulo". (The "MMM" acronym sounds catchy but I'm not using it yet.)

The method is not totally original, as Richard Schroeppel, Sean Anderson and Bruce Dawson (see credits below) each discovered one variant of the algorithm. I came up with all other variants that I can think of. And here is the list:

## List of optimal bit counting algorithms

Sorted by number of bits of the input (hereafter `x`).

**2-bit integer bit count**

Perhaps nothing can beat this (it's too trivial):

```c
x - (x >> 1);
```

**3-bit integer bit count**

(a.) A 16-bit constant lookup might generate the smallest code:

```c
/* 0xE994U == 0b11'10'10'01'10'01'0100U */
(0xE994U >> (x * 2)) & 0x3;
```

(b.) The "multiply-mask-multiply" method would use only 8-bit registers but usually results in larger code, and thus not recommended:

```c
(uint8_t)(((x * 0x9) & 0x55) * 0x55) >> 6;
```

**4-bit integer bit count**

(a.) If 64-bit registers are available, a 64-bit constant lookup might generate the smallest code:

```c
/* 0x8DA691691448ULL == octal 04332322132212110ULL */
(0x8DA691691448ULL >> (x * 3)) & 0x7;
(0x4332322132212110ULL >> (x * 4)) & 0x7;
```

(b.) Or, alternatively, use a 16-byte lookup table such as this:

```c
static const unsigned char bit_count_table[16] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4
};
```

(c.) Use the 5-bit version of the "multiply-mask-multiply" method (see below).

(d.) The "parallel-addition" method of counting a 4-bit integer can work with only 8-bit registers, but usually results in larger code, and thus not recommended:

```c
unsigned int bit_count_4_bits_d(uint8_t x)
{
    uint8_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x5);
    return (tmp & 0x3) + (tmp >> 2);
}
```

**5-bit integer bit count**

Both "multiply-mask-multiply" and "multiply-mask-modulo" are available. They use only 16-bit registers. The "multiply" variant is preferred if the modulo operation is expensive for your processor or the compiler would optimize divisions (e.g. "-O2" mode).

```c
/* 0x0421U == (1U | (1U << 5) | (1U << 10))
   0x1249U == octal 011111U */
(uint16_t)(((x * 0x0421U) & 0x1249U) * (0x1249U << 1)) >> 13;
(uint16_t)((x * 0x0421U) & 0x1249U) % 7;
```

**6-bit and 7-bit integer bit counts**

The "multiply-mask-multiply" and "-modulo" methods require at least 32-bit registers. All these four variants would work, so pick one that yields the smallest assembly for your processor. The first "modulo 7" variant works with only 6 bits of `x`; others 7 bits of `x`.

```c
/* 0x4081U == (1U | (1U << 7) | (1U << 14))
   0x049249UL == octal 01111111UL
   0x204081UL == (1U | (1U << 7) | (1U << 14) | (1UL << 21)) */

/* Works with only 6 bits of x */
(uint32_t)((x * 0x4081U) & 0x049249UL) % 7;
/* Works with 7 bits of x */
(uint32_t)(((x * 0x4081U) & 0x049249UL) * (0x049249UL << 11)) >> 29;
(uint32_t)(((x * 0x204081UL) & 0x11111111UL) * 0x11111111UL) >> 28;
(uint32_t)((x * 0x204081UL) & 0x01111111UL) % 15;
```

**8-bit integer bit count**

(a.) The "multiply-mask-multiply" and "-modulo" methods, using only 32-bit registers:

```c
/* 0x08040201UL == (1U | (1U << 9) | (1UL << 18) | (1UL << 27)) */
(uint32_t)((((x * 0x08040201UL) >> 3) & 0x11111111UL) * 0x11111111UL) >> 28;
(uint32_t)(((x * 0x08040201UL) >> 3) & 0x11111111UL) % 15;
```

(b.) A hybrid approach, which performs bits addition in the first step, then uses "multiply-mask-multiply" (or "-modulo") on the quaternary (base-4) digits. This uses 16-bit registers.

```c
unsigned int bit_count_8_bits_b(uint8_t x)
{
    uint16_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55);
    tmp = ((tmp * 0x0401U) >> 2) & 0x3333U;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 15); */
    return (uint16_t)(tmp * 0x1111U) >> 12;
}
```

(c.) The traditional, "parallel-addition" method. Only 8-bit registers would be needed in this method. (Note the final step may be performed with either a "multiply-shift" or a modulo.)

```c
unsigned int bit_count_8_bits_c(uint8_t x)
{
    uint8_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x33) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x33);
    /* Or: return (tmp % 15); */
    return (uint8_t)(tmp * 0x11) >> 4;
}
```

**9-bit integer bit count**

Original credit goes to Richard Schroeppel. From [*HAKMEM Item 167*](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html#item167). This "multiply-mask-modulo" requires a 64-bit register.

```c
/* <http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html#item167>
   The first multiplier fits a 32-bit register, otherwise this brings
   no advantage over the 14-bit version below. */
(((uint64_t)x * 0x08040201ULL) & 0x0111111111ULL) % 15;
```

**14-bit and 15-bit integer bit counts**

(a.) Credit goes to Sean Eron Anderson and Bruce Dawson. From [*Bit Twiddling Hacks*](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSet64). The "modulo 15" variant works with only 14 bits of `x`; the multiply variant works with 15 bits of `x`.

```c
/* <https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSet64>
   The version with modulo works with 14 bits of x only.
   0x200040008001ULL == (1U | (1U << 15) | (1UL << 30) | (1ULL << 45))
*/
((x * 0x200040008001ULL) & 0x0111111111111111ULL) % 15;

/* This version works with 15 bits of x */
(uint64_t)(((x * 0x200040008001ULL) & 0x1111111111111111ULL) \
 * 0x1111111111111111ULL) >> 60;
```

(b.) A hybrid approach, which performs bits addition in the first step, then uses "multiply-mask-multiply" (or "-modulo") on the quaternary (base-4) digits.

```c
unsigned int bit_count_15_bits_b(uint16_t x)
{
    uint32_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x5555U);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x4001UL) & 0x33333333UL;
    /* If we use "return (tmp % 15);" then up to 14-bits of x can
       be counted (one less than using the multiply). */
    return (uint32_t)(tmp * 0x11111111UL) >> 28;
}
```

**16-bit integer bit count**

(a.) Essentially `(x & 1) + bit_count_15_bits(x >> 1)`

```c
(x & 1) + ((uint64_t)((((x >> 1) * 0x200040008001ULL) \
 & 0x1111111111111111ULL) * 0x1111111111111111ULL) >> 60);
```

(b.) The "parallel-addition" method that is well written in many textbooks. (Note the final step may be performed with either a "multiply-shift" or a modulo.)

```c
unsigned int bit_count_16_bits_b(uint16_t x)
{
    uint16_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x5555U);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x3333U) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x3333U);
    tmp = (tmp + (tmp >> 4)) & 0x0F0FU;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint16_t)(tmp * 0x0101U) >> 8;
}
```

**20-bit and 22-bit integer bit counts**

These both use hybrid approaches. They perform bits addition in the first step, then use "multiply-mask-multiply" on the quaternary (base-4) digits:

```c
unsigned int bit_count_20_bits(uint32_t x)
{
    /* 0x010000100001ULL == (1U | (1UL << 20) | (1ULL << 40))
       0x00C30C30C30C30C3ULL == octal 00003030303030303030303ULL
       0x0820820820820820ULL == octal 00040404040404040404040ULL */
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x055555UL);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x010000100001ULL) & 0x00C30C30C30C30C3ULL;
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * 0x0820820820820820ULL) >> 59;
}

unsigned int bit_count_22_bits(uint32_t x)
{
    /* 0x080000200001ULL == (1U | (1UL << 21) | (1ULL << 43)) */
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x155555UL);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x080000200001ULL) & 0x18618618618C30C3ULL;
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * 0x0820821041041041ULL) >> 59;
}
```

**28-bit integer bit count**

(a.) This stacks two "multiply-mask-modulo" method of `bit_count_14_bits()`, i.e. `bit_count_14_bits(x & 0x3FFF) + bit_count_14_bits(x >> 14)`. The *Bit Twiddling Hacks* page mentioned the 24-bit version but it's possible to extend it to 28 bits.

```c
(((x & 0x3FFF) * 0x200040008001ULL) & 0x0111111111111111ULL) % 15 \
 + (((x >> 14) * 0x200040008001ULL) & 0x0111111111111111ULL) % 15;
```

(b.) This is a simplification of the "parallel-addition" counting code of a 32-bit integer. Read the 32-bit integer counting code below, before trying to understand this one.

```c
unsigned int bit_count_28_bits_b1(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x05555555UL);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x03333333UL) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x03333333UL);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x0111U) & 0x0F00F00FUL;
    return (uint32_t)(tmp * 0x01001001UL) >> 24;
}

unsigned int bit_count_28_bits_b2(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x05555555UL);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x03333333UL) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x03333333UL);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x11) & 0x0F0F0F0FUL;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint32_t)(tmp * 0x01010101UL) >> 24;
}
```

**30-bit integer bit count**

This stacks two "multiply-mask-multiply" method of `bit_count_15_bits()`, i.e. `bit_count_15_bits(x & 0x7FFF) + bit_count_15_bits(x >> 15)`.

```c
((uint64_t)((((x & 0x7FFF) * 0x200040008001ULL) \
 & 0x1111111111111111ULL) * 0x1111111111111111ULL) >> 60) \
 + ((uint64_t)((((x >> 15) * 0x200040008001ULL) \
 & 0x1111111111111111ULL) * 0x1111111111111111ULL) >> 60);
```

The "multiply-mask-multiply" method will become inefficient for counting bits if the input exceeds 30 bits.

**32-bit integer bit count**

(a.) The "parallel-addition" method that is well written in many textbooks:

```c
unsigned int bit_count_32_bits_a(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555UL);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x33333333UL) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x33333333UL);
    tmp = (tmp + (tmp >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0FUL;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint32_t)(tmp * 0x01010101UL) >> 24;
}
```

(b.) If the processor supports 64-bit registers and an efficient load of a 64-bit constant, a simplification can be performed so the code can become this:

```c
unsigned int bit_count_32_bits_b(uint32_t x)
{
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555UL);
    tmp = (tmp & 0x33333333UL) + ((tmp >> 2) & 0x33333333UL);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x0111U) & 0xF00F00F0UL;
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * 0x0010010010000000ULL) >> 56;
}
```

**60-bit integer bit count**

This is a simplification of the counting code of a 64-bit integer. Read the 64-bit integer counting code below, before trying to understand this one.

```c
unsigned int bit_count_60_bits_a1(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t mask1 = 0x0555555555555555ULL;
    uint64_t mask2 = 0x0333333333333333ULL;
    uint64_t mask4 = 0x0F00F00F00F00F00ULL;
    uint64_t multiplier = 0x0001001001001001ULL;
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & mask1);
    tmp = (tmp & mask2) + ((tmp >> 2) & mask2);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x0111U) & mask4;
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * multiplier) >> 56;
}

unsigned int bit_count_60_bits_a2(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t mask1 = 0x0555555555555555ULL;
    uint64_t mask2 = 0x0333333333333333ULL;
    uint64_t mask4 = 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL;
    uint64_t multiplier = 0x0101010101010101ULL;
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & mask1);
    tmp = (tmp & mask2) + ((tmp >> 2) & mask2);
    tmp = (tmp * 0x11) & mask4;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * multiplier) >> 56;
}
```

**64-bit, 128-bit and 255-bit integer bit counts**

The "parallel-addition" method that is well written in many textbooks. Up to 255 bits can count this way.

The 255-bit variant is not shown here (very few compilers support `uint128_t` already, let alone 256-bit types), but basically you know how to do it (the 255-bit variant cannot use the modulo in the final step).

(256 bits would overflow the storage of 8-bit temporary results, but can workaround with `(x & 1) + bit_count_255_bits(x >> 1)`)

```c
unsigned int bit_count_64_bits(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t mask1 = 0x5555555555555555ULL;
    uint64_t mask2 = 0x3333333333333333ULL;
    uint64_t mask4 = 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0FULL;
    uint64_t multiplier = 0x0101010101010101ULL;
    uint64_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & mask1);
    tmp = (tmp & mask2) + ((tmp >> 2) & mask2);
    tmp = (tmp + (tmp >> 4)) & mask4;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint64_t)(tmp * multiplier) >> 56;
}

unsigned int bit_count_128_bits(uint128_t x)
{
    uint128_t mask1 = (UINT128_MAX / 0xFF) * 0x55;
    uint128_t mask2 = (UINT128_MAX / 0xFF) * 0x33;
    uint128_t mask4 = (UINT128_MAX / 0xFF) * 0x0F;
    uint128_t multiplier = (UINT128_MAX / 0xFF);
    uint128_t tmp = x - ((x >> 1) & mask1);
    tmp = (tmp & mask2) + ((tmp >> 2) & mask2);
    tmp = (tmp + (tmp >> 4)) & mask4;
    /* Or: return (tmp % 255); */
    return (uint128_t)(tmp * multiplier) >> 120;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of digits different than 0 is also known as a [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight). In this case, you are counting the number of 1's.

Dasblinkenlight provided you with a table driven implementation, and Olaf provided you with a software based solution. I think you have two other potential solutions. The first is to use a compiler extension, the second is to use an ASM specific instruction with inline assembly from C.

For the first alternative, see GCC's [`__builtin_popcount()`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). (Thanks to Artless Noise).

For the second alternative, you did not specify the embedded processor, but I'm going to offer this in case its ARM based.

Some ARM processors have the [`VCNT`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/CIHCFDBJ.html) instruction, which performs the count for you. So you could do it from C with inline assembly:

```c
inline
unsigned int hamming_weight(unsigned char value) {
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "VCNT.8"
            : "=value"
            : "value"
    );

    return value;
}
```

Also see [Fastest way to count number of 1s in a register, ARM assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736602).

---

For completeness, here is Kernighan's bit counting algorithm:

```c
int count_bits(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while(n != 0) {
        n &= (n-1);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also see [Please explain the logic behind Kernighan's bit counting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12383002).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the fastest, but straightforward:

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    unsigned char c = 1 << i;
    if (yourVar & c) {
        //bit n°i is set
        //first bit is bit n°0
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 8/16 bit MCUs, a loop will very likely be faster than the parallel-addition approach, as these MCUs cannot shift by more than one bit per instruction, so:

```
size_t popcount(uint8_t val)
{
    size_t cnt = 0;
    do {
        cnt += val & 1U;    // or: if ( val & 1 ) cnt++;
    } while ( val >>= 1 ) ;
    return cnt;
}
```

For the incrementation of cnt, you might profile. If still too slow, an assember implementation might be worth a try using carry flag (if available). While I am in against using assembler optimizations in general, such algorithms are one of the few good exceptions (still just after the C version fails).

If you can omit the Flash, a lookup table as proposed by @dasblinkenlight is likey the fastest approach.

Just a hint: For some architectures (notably ARM and x86/64), gcc has a builtin: `__builtin_popcount()`, you also might want to try if available (although it takes int at least). This might use a single CPU instruction - you cannot get faster and more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to post a second answer. This one is the smallest possible for ARM processors with Advanced SIMD extension (NEON). It's even smaller than `__builtin_popcount()` (since `__builtin_popcount()` is optimized for `unsigned int` input, not `uint8_t`).

```
#ifdef __ARM_NEON
/* ARM C Language Extensions (ACLE) recommends us to check __ARM_NEON before
   including <arm_neon.h> */
#include <arm_neon.h>

unsigned int bit_count_uint8(uint8_t x)
{
    /* Set all lanes at once so that the compiler won't emit instruction to
       zero-initialize other lanes. */
    uint8x8_t v = vdup_n_u8(x);
    /* Count the number of set bits for each lane (8-bit) in the vector. */
    v = vcnt_u8(v);
    /* Get lane 0 and discard other lanes. */
    return vget_lane_u8(v, 0);
}
#endif
```