# php Bitwize AND operation with Bigints

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an AND operation between 2 Bigints 
and then to count the number of bits 1 on binary representation.

Example :

$a and $b are bigints resulting of a MySql query.

$result = countones($a & $b);

with :

```
function countones($n){
  $c =0;
  while($n){
    $c += $n&1;
    $n = $n>>1;
  }
  return $c;
}
```

With Ints no problem. I've tried to use gmp functions but my attemps failed... I must be missing something...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fastest count the number of set bits in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848931/how-to-fastest-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can just CAST them as strings in SQL and then change `$n&1` to `substr($n,-1)&1` and `$n >>= 1;` to `$n = substr($n,0,-1);`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, at first I was thinking to do such thing but this operation must be done in a loop thousands of times, and I think that using bitwise will be much faster... if it is possible to do it with Bigints as well :-/

Comment: it is not possible since PHP doesn't have any built-in bigints which means that your database library would rely on functionality that isn't always there...

Comment: You are right, and it is useless to want to deal with BigInts as PHP is not ready for it. Instead I decided to use 2 fields Int (for performance reasons). The code was a bit longer, but is robust, and it works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This if course only works if the bigint isn't of unlimited size. But I guess it's usually not like that in SQL implementations even if bigint isn't part of the standard.