# big-Theta running time in terms of input size N

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

while N-bit integer a > 1,
         a = a / 2

I was thinking it is log(n) because each time you go through the while loop you are dividing a by two but my friend thinks  its 2 logn(n).

Comment: [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: What is your friends justification for that? Do you both agree on what n is?

Comment: the thing is we don't know what N is and what they mean by N-bit integer

Comment: Imagine that we have an 4-bit integer (that can hold a value from 0 to 15).  Is n 4, or 16?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bits counting algorithm (Brian Kernighan) in an integer time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380478/bits-counting-algorithm-brian-kernighan-in-an-integer-time-complexity). The last answer to that question (not the accepted answer) touches on the point I was making in my comments: do you and your friend agree on what n is?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your algorithm is in ***big-Theta(log(a))***, where ***a*** is your number

But as far as I understand your problem, you want to know the asymptotic runtime depending on the amount of bits of your number

That's really difficult to say and depends on your number:

Let's say you have an n-bit integer and the Most significant bit is 1. You have to divide it n-times, to get a number smaller than 1.

Now let's look at a integer where only the least siginficant bit is 1 (so it equals the number 1 in decimal system). There you need just one division.

So i would say, it'll take n/2 in average which makes it ***big-Theta(n)*** where ***n*** is the amount of bits of your number. The worst-case is also in ***big-Theta(n)*** and the best-case is in ***big-Theta(1)***

> **NOTE:** Dividing a number by two in binary system has a similar effect as dividing a number by ten in decimal system

Answer (score 0):

Dividing an integer by two can be efficiently implemented by taking a number in binary notation and shifting the bits. In the worst case, all the bits are set at you have to shift (n-1) bits for the first division, (n-2) bits for the second, etc. etc. until you shift 1 bit on the last iteration and find the number becomes equal to 1, at which point you stop. This means your algorithm must shift 1+2+...+(n-1) = n(n-1)/2 bits, making your algorithm `O(n^2)` in the number of bits of input.

A more efficient algorithm that will leave `a` with the same value is `a = (a == 0 ? 0 : 1)`. This generates the same answer in linear time (equality checking is linear in the number of bits) and it works because your code will only leave `a = 0` if `a` is originally zero; in all other cases, the highest-order bit ends up in the unit's place.