# how to use the bit operations to find the number of units with running time O (k)

Tags: algorithm, binary

How to use the bit operations to find the number of units with running time O (k),

**k - number of units in binary notation?**

```
    int n, ans;
    cin >> n;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1) {
            ans++;
        }
        n = (n >> 1);
    }
    cout << ans;
```

Time complexity of my solution is O(log n).
But I need O(k).

Comment: @Damien I don't think I get you. 10 is 1010, k = 2 and log n = 4. So k < log n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of units in binary notation = Number of set bits.

This is a [familiar problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/), you are looking for the [Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380478/bits-counting-algorithm-brian-kernighan-in-an-integer-time-complexity).

This algorithm works in `O(log N)`, but also in `O(K)`. In every iteration of the algorithm we unset the rightmost bit by performing `n & (n - 1)`, therefore after `K` iterations the number will be `0` and we are done.

So time complexity is number of units (number of set bits), which is `K`.